# Animation in Word

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016

I found a [tutorial](https://word.tips.net/T000613_Animating_Your_Text.html) to add animations to texts in Word 97. Is the feature still available in the latest version? If yes, please tell me where I can find it.

Comment: That type of "early html" animation style went out of fashion a very *very* long time ago. I found this for Word 2010… maybe it still works - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_other-mso_2010/special-effects-for-text/7bc82191-1102-4fc9-b7e7-7e63c54ff914

Comment: It is not available in the latest versions. This is true even if the document is in legacy .doc format. See my download for more http://www.addbalance.com/word/download.htm#FontTextEffectSampler.

Comment: Thank you for your effort! But the text effects no longer work on Word 2016 or 13 :(